# DSE Authenticate Spark AlwaysOn SQL

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph, datastax-startup

I've installed DSE (Cassandra + Search + Graph + Analytics) on a single for dev purposes and I'm not able to connect to the AlwaysOn SQL, it's enabled on dse.yaml file but I'm not sure how to set access / permissions.

Configurations:

cassandra.yaml:
authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator

dse.yaml:
authentication_options=enabled

hive-site.xml:
jdbc-auth-type=password

I'm not able to give access to the user "alwayson_sql" from CQLSH (cqlsh  -u cassandra -p cassandra):
Unauthorized: Error from server: code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="Anonymous users are not authorized to perform this request"

Based on this guide:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.0/security/secAuthSpark.html?hl=alwayson

What will be the right configuration / process to allow access to the AlwaysOn SQL? (for now security is not important it's a dev environment for testings only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't change authenticator to `AllowAllAuthenticator` - in DSE, you must use `com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator` (the same is for authorizer) & configure it via `dse.yaml` as [described in the documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.0/security/secAuthTOC.html) - configure `internal` authentication schema, and enable authorization options as well.

And because you're using `AllowAllAuthenticator`, then your user is not authenticated, even if you pass username/password, and this lead to the error that you receive.

After you configure authentication/authorization, you can continue login & configure AOSS access rights as [described in documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.0/security/secAuthSpark.html?hl=alwayson).

Comment: Thanks! after updating the config on OpsCnter the job failed with msg: Verifying the password for DSE user 'cassandra' - Do you know what have I missed?

Comment: You need explicitly set password for cassandra user in the configuration profile - it's a known bug in the OpsCenter LCM... For single dev environment, I recommend either just install DSE manually - you can even not use authentication/authorization, and AOSS just works out of box. Or you can use DataStax Desktop that uses Docker to rollout dev environment: https://downloads.datastax.com/#desktop

Comment: This is truly amazing! I missed this option, it's really fast deployment and beautiful UI :) + save costs on servers for developers, do you know when there will be a support for DSE 6.8? We need to use the Graph there is major improvements and functionality only on this version. Thank you! 

Comment: I really don’t know - can you ask at https://community.datastax.com/ ? I would expect that it should be really soon, as it depends only on Docker images...

Comment: Sure I will ask there. Do you know what is the default user and password for the AlwaysOn SQL on the docker image? Can't find it in the docs.

Comment: I don’t remember out of head, but there shouldn’t be any auth by default, so empty username password should work

Comment: The issue seems to be with the HIve version, How can I find out what version is being used on DSE 6.7 / 6.8?